# Sessions to Quickboks API crashing Server

Tags: session, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Open sessions to Quickbooks online is crashing server.

I'm finishing up an implementation of a Coldfusion app connecting to Quickbooks online.
I'm using coldfusion scheduled files to sync data. (Sending Invoices/Payments/Clients to QBO)
There have been a few times that the server has crashed due to open sessions to quickbooks.

I can't determine if the request connection for each object just isn't being "shut down", or if the initial query has the potential of just sending too many object requests? (we have lots of pre-existing data in the live testing account).

According to QBO docs:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/limits_and_throttles

*Requests are throttled at 100 request per minute per Company ID across all V3 endpoints.*

So no more than 100 can be accepted by QB in theory.

Please let me know what, if any specifics I can provide.

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: Are you using Java to connect Steve? Sometimes I add close/destroy commands to Java objects in CF because they end up staying around (usually due to specific required implimentations or badly behaving code).

Comment: We are using Java. I'll check that out. Thank you.

Comment: Steve, I many java objects have a finalize() method (in fact it may be a part of the base object class). You can often try simply running myJavaObject.finalize() at the end of your work with the object to clean it up. It works for objects in the memory management classes.